# What does "into" here mean? (Translate your thinking into English.)

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

> You will have to translate your thinking **into** English before
>   saying it.

Does **into** mean in that sentence that *you are thinking in English* OR that you are translating whatever you are thinking of to English? Because I want it to be the second meaning, but I've heard that **to** isn't the correct preposition there.

Comment: https://jakubmarian.com/translate-to-vs-translate-into-in-english/

Comment: @Alex_ander: re that site: "in most but the very literal senses" is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Alex_ander That artical is one of the most helpful ones I have ever read. If you can attach it to your answer so I can choose it as the acceptable one, and people would know why.

Comment: OK, I've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **the** preposition used after the verb '*to translate*', when the result of translation should be **in** some *language*. The *Oxford Collocation Dictionary* only mentions prepositions **as** (a particular word, phrase), **for** (someone), **from** (some language) and **into** (some language, some other expression).

**P.S.** Here's an article explaining the details of using '**to**' instead of '**into**' where possible:
https://jakubmarian.com/translate-to-vs-translate-into-in-english/

Comment: That said, it's not like the prepositions that get mentioned in the dictionary are the only valid allowable ones. For example, there is nothing wrong with saying "translated **by** (someone)," even though that usage doesn't get an explicit mention: _This edition was translated by Howard_.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you will have to translate the thoughts that are in your head from your mother tongue to English. People who don't speak a foreign language very well tend to first form sentences in their mother tongue and then mentally translate them to the foreign language they want to express their thoughts in.

<sup>(transcribed from comment)</sup>